# UACbypass running command as Administrator and get output in Python

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess, uac

Is there any way to use uacbypass and run the command as Administrator also get the output in Python?
Just run the command as Administrator without uac screen and get the output

What I expect:

```py
run(CMD):
    # run the command as administrator
    return output
```